# Ubuntu slow when laptop connected to power

Tags: boot, power-management, cpu

I've already had this problem before but I don't know how I solved it.

Ubuntu becomes very slow (mouse jumps from point to point) when I connect to power. The problem was related to a CPU feature that was activated when power was connected. I don't remember which feature it was. Can someone remember it?

When the system initiates, it takes some seconds for the computer to freeze, like it was the start of some process that made the slowness start

Answer (score 1):

Could have something to do with C-States or P-states which refer to power modes that a CPU can use in order to efficiently use power/frequency without loosing performance. Here’s a post that explains [the details](https://metebalci.com/blog/a-minimum-complete-tutorial-of-cpu-power-management-c-states-and-p-states/#p-states).

I had a laptop that used to freeze because of a non-supported c-state and had to set intel_idle.max_cstate=1 to my GRUB configuration as a boot parameter 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in 
`/etc/default/grub`

A useful place to know more about your cpu frequency managment is:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver`

mine is: `acpi-cpufreq`

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors`

mine are: `conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance`

Would be curious to know how it goes

Comment: this problem hasn't happened for years but it just happened now for no reason. `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors` gives me `performance powersave` both on AC and without AC connection

Comment: and my scaling driver is `intel_pstate`

Comment: the boot parameter didn't work. Something important: the slowness starts after some time after the system intiates, like it was something starting up in the system

Comment: I've found the solution, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I was using a faulty power extender. The ubuntu wouldn't show it was charging but the connection kinda worked and I think the CPU was making up for the slow energy it was receiving. I simply connected the charger directly to the AC and it worked and showed it was charging